# Bluetooth is unable to find any device, it keeps searching on and on

Tags: bluetooth, 17.04

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu 17.04 laptop to Bluetooth speakers (visibility is on), but it keeps on searching and searching, it's not even able to find any other Bluetooth devices.

I tried to find laptop through my smartphone, but my smartphone is able to find everything except Ubuntu laptop.

Can anybody help me with this?

---

Here are the details.

output `rfkill`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `dmesg | grep Blue`

```
[   21.833554] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.833595] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.833601] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.833605] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.833614] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.960162] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   21.976142] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   21.976147] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   22.029898] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   24.033855] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   25.592338] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   25.592340] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   25.592346] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   33.864100] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   33.864111] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   33.864117] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: NAMI
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b50a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c9e:9ba1 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: its regarding wifi i guess, wifi is working fine.Issue is with bluetooth.

Comment: added few other details...

Comment: Can anybody help on this...